# Powershell- pass $_.FullName with spaces to batch file

Tags: powershell

I'd like to pass a directory full path to a test batch script with all spaces and special characters and read it inside the batch file.
the problem is that the directory path contains spaces and semicolon (name followed by the timestamp like "abcdefg yyyy-mm-dd hh;mm;ss")
With the powershell script below i'm searching for the directory having the given pattern in a specific path and then pass their name to the batch file.

test.ps1 code:

```
Param([string]$path, [string]$searchStr)
$filenameregex = "^$($searchStr)\s\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}" 
get-childitem -Path $path -Directory |where-object{$_.Name -match $filenameregex} | Sort CreationTime -desc | Select -Skip 4 | ForEach-Object {$A=start-process -FilePath testBacth.bat -ArgumentList $_.FullName -Wait -passthru;$A.exitcode}
```

The bacth simply writes the parameter to a file.

testbatch.bat code:

ECHO %~1 >> out.txt

When i run the script with

```
test.ps1 -path \\nosrvfnas0001\bak\nosrvfdati0001\ -str Shared
```

this is the output i get:

```
\\nosrvfnas0001\bak\nosrvfdati0001\Shared 
\\nosrvfnas0001\bak\nosrvfdati0001\Shared 
\\nosrvfnas0001\bak\nosrvfdati0001\Shared
```

the timestamp part is missing !!!

I think that this is due to spaces inside fullname property , but idon't know how to pass the entire fullname to the .bat file.

Comment: The command line that you have showing how you run the script would not run the way you say it does. $searchStr would not get a value

Comment: It was a typo. the command line is test.ps1 -path \\nosrvfnas0001\bak\nosrvfdati0001\ -searchstr Shared

Comment: Why do you need a batch file at all? Just do whatever you need directly in PowerShell.

Comment: The bat file here is for test purpose. I need To know To Pass The full path To The batch .

Comment: pass full path with '' signs like -ArgumentList ("'$_.FullName'") this will pass full name in ' ' marks and should solve Your issue